# How to detect more than one regex in a case_when statement

Tags: r

I have recently converted from ifelse to `case_when` from `dplyr`.

**Aim**

I would like to be able to detect more than one regex from a statement in a dataframe using `case_when` as follows:

**Input**

```
statement<-data.frame(statement = c("I have performed APC and RFA",
 "An EMR was done","I didn't do anything"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Desired output**

```
statement                            out

I have performed APC and RFA        APC,RFA
An EMR was done                     EMR
I didn't do anything                No Event
```

**Attempt**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

      dataframe <- 
        dataframe %>% 
        mutate(
          EVENT = case_when(
            str_detect(statement,"EMR") ~ "EMR", 
            str_detect(statement, "HALO|RFA") ~ "RFA", 
            str_detect(statement, "APC") ~ "APC", 
             TRUE ~ "No Event"
          )
        )
```

**The problem**

This gives only one output per statement rather than multiple output if multiple strings are present. Is there a way to detect multiple strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) gsubfn::strapply** `strapply` can do the extraction and translation all at once. `strapply` will, for each component of `stmt`, match the pattern `pat` to it and all matches will be translated using L and then returned.  The `empty` argument defines what is returned for components of `stat` having no matches. This gives a list of matches, one list component per row, on which `toString` is applied to convert each to a comma separated character string.  This is the shortest of the 3 alternatives presented here.

```
library(gsubfn)

L <- list(APC = "APC", EMR = "EMR", HALO = "RFA", RFA = "RFA")
pat <- paste(names(L), collapse = "|")
transform(statement, 
  out = sapply(strapply(stmt, pat, L, empty = "No Event"), toString),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
                          stmt      out
1 I have performed APC and RFA APC, RFA
2              An EMR was done      EMR
3         I didn't do anything No Event
```

**2) Base R**  Using `L` and `pat` from above, create a function which takes a character vector of words `x` and extracts out those words matched by `pat` into `g`.  If `g` has non-zero length translate its elements using `L` and compress it into a single string using `toString`; otherwise, return `No Event`.

Now split each element of `stmt` into words using `strsplit` and apply `process` to each such character vector.

```
process <- function(x) {
  g <- grep(pat, x, value = TRUE)
  if (length(g)) toString(L[g]) else "No Event"
}
transform(statement, out = sapply(strsplit(stmt, "\\s+"), process),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr** Using `L` from (1) group by row number and `stmt` and separate the words into separate rows.  Filter out those words in `names(L)` and collapse all rows in one `stmt` group translating through `L` and using `toString` to generate a comma separated string.  Drop the `n` column. At this point we have the desired result except that `No Event` rows are still missing so right join what we have with `statement` and replace NAs with `No Event`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

statement %>%
  group_by(n = 1:n(), out = stmt) %>%
  separate_rows(out) %>%
  filter(out %in% names(L)) %>%
  summarize(stmt = stmt[1], out = toString(L[out])) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  right_join(statement, by = "stmt") %>%
  mutate(out = if_else(is.na(out), "No Event", out))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  stmt                         out     
  <chr>                        <chr>   
1 I have performed APC and RFA APC, RFA
2 An EMR was done              EMR     
3 I didn't do anything         No Event
```

### Note

We used this as the input:

```
statement <- structure(list(stmt = c("I have performed APC and RFA", 
  "An EMR was done", "I didn't do anything")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

### Updates

Have revised a number of times after re-reading the question. Also added more alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck. I have similar situation with a little difference. I got a weird result with ```case_when```. My case_when statement is such as: ```mutate(           EVENT = case_when(             str_detect(statement,"30 multiple conditions") ~ "EMR",              str_detect(statement, "30 multiple conditions") ~ "RFA",              str_detect(statement, "30 multiple conditions") ~ "APC",               TRUE ~ "statement"           )``` What do I do in this case?

Comment: @Wialliam, You can't use the same condition multiple times. If the first one is true it will return its right hand side if it is false all of them will be false and it will return the default. thus the subsequent duplicate conditions can never match.  Suggest you read `?case_when` and review the examples at the bottom of that page as well as as many SO examples as you can find.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of `case_when` is that it doesn't execute the remaining conditions once a condition is met, so you can't actually get two outputs from a `case_when` statement. So if you want to use `case_when` it is advised to start with a least common condition and then slowly keep on making it more general. (hence, `TRUE` is the last condition)

If you want to stick with `case_when` you can add an additional condition and check for both the cases separately and give output accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)

statement %>% 
     mutate(
     EVENT = case_when(
           str_detect(statement, "APC") & str_detect(statement, "RFA") ~ "APC,RFA",
           str_detect(statement,"EMR") ~ "EMR", 
           str_detect(statement, "HALO|RFA") ~ "RFA", 
           str_detect(statement, "APC") ~ "APC", 
           TRUE ~ "No Event"
            )
           )



#                     statement    EVENT
#1 I have performed APC and RFA  APC,RFA
#2              An EMR was done      EMR
#3         I didn't do anything No Event
#4                        FALSE No Event
```

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. Unfortuntely this isnt really a scalable answer and I dont want to create every permutation of str_detect if it does scale up

Answer (score 0):

An idea via base R is to extract the words with all upper case letters, and paste the ones that are bigger than 1 character, i.e.,

```
sapply(regmatches(statement$statement, gregexpr('\\b[A-Z]+\\b', statement$statement)), 
                                          function(i) {
                                                      v1 <- i[nchar(i) > 1];
                                                      toString(v1)
                                                      })


#[1] "APC, RFA" "EMR"      ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `case_when` is the best way to go. I think it depends a little bit on how many mappings like `"HALO|RFA"` you have. If there are many, it might be worth the time to write a proper function. However, if it is just this one, it might be faster to put together a pipe using dplyr verbs.

I would suggest using `str_extract_all` and `unnest` to get a tidy data frame with the relevant verbs and then use `str_replace_all` to resolve the mapping. In the end, I would use `unique` to make sure that we have no duplicate rows from the replacements.

Notice that the first column with APC, RFA will be split in two. I realize that this is not what you asked but it will make susequent processing in the tidyverse much easier. See this link for more on tidy data conventions: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html

In it's current implementation, `unnest` will drop the last row where no pattern was matched. If you would like a `NA` instead, you can perform a `full join` with the original data. See also https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/358

```
statement<-data.frame(statement = c("I have performed APC and RFA","An EMR was done","I didn't do anything"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
statement %>% mutate(
  out = statement %>% 
    str_extract_all("((EMR)|(HALO)|(RFA)|(APC))")
  ) %>%  unnest(.drop =FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(
    out = out %>% str_replace_all("HALO", "RFA")
  ) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  full_join(statement)
```

The output will be

```
                 statement    out
I have performed APC and RFA  APC
I have performed APC and RFA  RFA
An EMR was done               EMR
I didn't do anything          <NA>
```

Comment: the output only gives me one result. For example the first text string only outputs APC