# R: any perfect alternative to case_when() when detecting strings with multiple conditions and replacing them?

Tags: r, regex, text, dplyr, stringr

I applied `case_when` to a text data of thousands of rows to detect strings with multiple conditions and replace them but got a wrong result because `case_when` doesn't execute the remaining conditions once a condition is met. I have seen a solution in [How to detect more than one regex in a case_when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851627/how-to-detect-more-than-one-regex-in-a-case-when-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the solution does not have multiplicity of multiple conditions such as in my data.

Any alternative to `case_when` will be is appreciated.

This is the dummy data:

```
statement <- structure(list(stmt = c("diabetes is common", "police not my friend"
  "transport is cheap", "english is my language", "education is my right")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I tried to adapt the 1st solution in [How to detect more than one regex in a case_when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851627/how-to-detect-more-than-one-regex-in-a-case-when-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1) but could not really figure it out.

I want to detect strings in texts in column `stmt` and recode the column into these five domains: `APC`, `PDP`, `APGA`, `APP` and `SDP`. Below are strings to be detected:

```
APC <- c("addiction|mental||Diabetes|health|healthy|Oranga|unwell|AOD| well| surgery|dental|recovery|oranga|Mirimiri|asthma|anger|checks|alcohol|pregnant|clinical|clinic")

PDP <- c("whanau direct|whānau direct|money|transport|home|repairs|social|budget|job|housing|house|financial|finance|Ohanga|furniture|accommodation|welfare|living|work|babies arrival|AT hop card|Entitlements|ohunga|bills|electricity|water|employment")

APGA <- c("Kaupapa|Te reo|language|Tikanga|Iwi|relationship|Tikinga|Reunite|")

APP <- c("Studying|training|NCEA|ECE|Counseling|counsel|Knowledge|School|Education|matauranga|parenting|skills")

rangatiratanga <- c("self-management|Rangitiratanga|custody|police|court|CYFS|advocacy|Oranga Tamariki|rangatiratanga|section 101|EPOA|Familly issues")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `case_when` with `grepl` and a regex alternation:

```
statement$col <- case_when(
    grepl("(addiction|mental|Diabetes|health|healthy|Oranga|unwell|AOD| well| surgery|dental|recovery|oranga|Mirimiri|asthma|anger|checks|alcohol|pregnant|clinical|clinic)", statement$stmt) ~ "APC",
    grepl("(whanau direct|whānau direct|money|transport|home|repairs|social|budget|job|housing|house|financial|finance|Ohanga|furniture|accommodation|welfare|living|work|babies arrival|AT hop card|Entitlements|ohunga|bills|electricity|water|employment)", statement$stmt) ~ "PDP",
    grepl("(Kaupapa|Te reo|language|Tikanga|Iwi|relationship|Tikinga|Reunite)", statement$stmt) ~ "APGA",
    grepl("(Studying|training|NCEA|ECE|Counseling|counsel|Knowledge|School|Education|matauranga|parenting|skills)", statement$stmt) ~ "APP",
    grepl("(self-management|Rangitiratanga|custody|police|court|CYFS|advocacy|Oranga Tamariki|rangatiratanga|section 101|EPOA|Familly issues)", statement$stmt) ~ "rangatiratanga",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
)
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, can you check your code? It throws up an error: ```Error: must be a character vector, not a logical vector.```

Comment: @William I have tested my general syntax locally and it is working.  Maybe you copied my code wrongly or maybe have you changed it from you see exactly above?

Comment: @William @Tim You probably need to change it to `TRUE ~ NA_character_`.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks...I would have thought that a character vector can store an `NA` value.

Comment: Hi @Tim, i have to modified your code to make it work. I have to change `TRUE ~ NA` to `TRUE ~ NA_character_`. Thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually class of `NA` is logical but it would have still worked with `base::ifelse` because it automatically converts logical NA to character NA. However, `dplyr::if_else` or `dplyr::case_when` don't do that. You need to explicitly specify type of `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tim Biegeleisen, but detecting strings ordinarily using `case_when()` & `grepl()` may throw up errors, if cases are not ignored. The `grepl()` can include `ignore.case = T` argument in order to make string matching case insensitive, such as in the code below:

```
statement$col <- case_when(
      grepl(ignore.case = T, "(addiction|mental|Diabetes|health|healthy|Oranga|unwell|AOD| well| surgery|dental|recovery|oranga|Mirimiri|asthma|anger|checks|alcohol|pregnant|clinical|clinic)", statement$stmt) ~ "APC",
      grepl(ignore.case = T, "(whanau direct|whānau direct|money|transport|home|repairs|social|budget|job|housing|house|financial|finance|Ohanga|furniture|accommodation|welfare|living|work|babies arrival|AT hop card|Entitlements|ohunga|bills|electricity|water|employment)", statement$stmt) ~ "PDP",
      grepl(ignore.case = T, "(Kaupapa|Te reo|language|Tikanga|Iwi|relationship|Tikinga|Reunite)", statement$stmt) ~ "APGA",
      grepl(ignore.case = T, "(Studying|training|NCEA|ECE|Counseling|counsel|Knowledge|School|Education|matauranga|parenting|skills)", statement$stmt) ~ "APP",
      grepl(ignore.case = T, "(self-management|Rangitiratanga|custody|police|court|CYFS|advocacy|Oranga Tamariki|rangatiratanga|section 101|EPOA|Familly issues)", statement$stmt) ~ "rangatiratanga",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
```